SPI flash memory (AT26DF161A) with PIC16F883 write wrong data in memory and Manufacturer ID is wrong
I'm working on a product with a TFT display and I want to save the screens in a flash memory.
I had available an AT26DF161A memory, so I build a prototype in order to test it with a PIC16F883.
I wrote the code just to send a 20 char array with ascii characters, read it back and send it through UART comm to the PC terminal with a USB to Serial converter.
First of all, when I check the device manufaturer ID, instead of 1Fh, I recieve 58h. However, both bytes of Device ID are ok, 46h and 01h. I don't know if this is a bad component or if the manufacturer ID changed and they forgot to update the datasheet.
The most important problem, is that I'm wititng to the memory the array, but when I read it all the data saved is wrong, there is data where I tried to write my array, but is not what I wrote.
Below you'll find the code I've written.
EDIT1
The array I'm sending to the memory is this:
{41h 42h 43h 44h 45h 46h 47h 48h 49h 4Ah 4Bh 4Ch 4Dh 4Eh 4Fh 50h 00h 00h 00h 00h} (in ascii is {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}...
and the response is:
{43h 0Ah 28h 12h 4Dh 24h FFh 62h FFh 2Ch FFh FFh FFh 32h FFh 30h 00h 00h 00h 00h}
After this I've tried again and the response was this {43h 0Ah 28h 12h 4Dh 24h FFh 51h 59h FFh 5Dh 45h 65h FFh 75h 18h 00h 00h 00h 00h}.
First I unprotect the sector, then I perform a 4kB erase and then I write, If I don't do this, the response is all FFh.
The chip is marked as Atmel, I don't know why the response is another manufacturer.
/*MEM_HAL_functions.h*/

#define CMD_SEQUENTIAL_MODE     0xAF
#define CMD_BYTE_PAGE_WRITE     0x02
#define CMD_WRITE_EN            0x06
#define CMD_WRITE_DIS           0x04
#define CMD_READ_ARRAY          0x0B
#define CMD_READ_ARRAY_LF       0x03
#define CMD_READ_STAT_REG       0x05
#define CMD_WRITE_STAT_REG      0x01
#define CMD_CHIP_ERASE          0x60
#define CMD_GLOBAL_UNPROT       0x00
#define CMD_GLOBAL_PROT         0x3C
#define CMD_UNPROTECT_SECTOR    0x39
#define CMD_PROTECT_SECTOR      0x36
#define CMD_READ_DEV_ID         0x9F
#define DEV_ID_OK               0xCC
#define DEV_ID_NOK              0xDD
#define UPDATE_STAT_REG         0x11
#define NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG      0x22
#define MEM_STAT_REG_ERROR      0xFF
#define MEM_WRITE_ERROR         0xBB
#define MEM_WRITE_OK            0xAA
#define WEL_BIT                 31
#define EPE_BIT                 35
#define RDY_BSY_BIT             30
#define SPM_BIT                 36
#define MASK_SPM_BIT        0b01000000
#define SPM_BIT_ON          0x01
#define SPM_BIT_POS         6
#define MASK_WEL_BIT        0b00000010
#define WEL_BIT_POS         1
#define WEL_BIT_ON          0b00000010
#define EPE_ERROR           0xEE
#define MASK_EPE_BIT        0b00100000
#define EPE_BIT_POS         5
#define EPE_BIT_NO_ERR      0b00000000
#define RDY_BSY_BIT_POS     0
#define MASK_RDY_BSY_BIT    0b00000001
#define RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY    0b00000001
#define SCREEN0_ADD_0       0x00
#define SCREEN0_ADD_1       0x01
#define SCREEN0_ADD_2       0x00
#define SCREEN1_ADD_0       0x00
#define SCREEN1_ADD_1       0x58
#define SCREEN1_ADD_2       0x02
#define DUMMY_BYTE          0x55
#define MEM_CS_SETTLE_TIME  10      //uS
#define BLOCK_4KB_ERASE_CMD     0x20
#define BLOCK_32KB_ERASE_CMD    0x52
#define BLOCK_64KB_ERASE_CMD    0x68
#define ALL_BLOCKS_ERASE_CMD    0x60

#define BLOCK_4KB               4
#define BLOCK_32KB              32
#define BLOCK_64KB              64
#define ALL_BLOCKS              255

void MemCSEnable(void);
void MemCSDisable(void);
char MemStatRegBitCheck (char bit2check, char update_stat_reg);
void TxSPIData2Mem(char* data,char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0);
void RxSPIMemData(char* data,char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0);
char MemWritePageByte (char* data, char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0);
void MemGlobalUnprotect (void);
void MemUnprotectSector (char address2, char address1, char address0);
void MemErase(char block_size, char address2, char address1, char address0);
char MemReadDeviceID (char* data);

/*MEM_HAL_functions.c*/
#include    "MEM_HAL_functions.h"
#include    "PIC16F883_HAL_functions.h"

void MemCSEnable(void)
{
    MEM_CS_ON;                    //Habilito la memoria
    __delay_us(MEM_CS_SETTLE_TIME);
}
void MemCSDisable(void)
{
    MEM_CS_OFF;                     //Habilito la memoria
    __delay_us(MEM_CS_SETTLE_TIME);
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*       Chequear el estado del bit indicado del StatReg                      */
/******************************************************************************/
char MemStatRegBitCheck (char bit2check, char update_stat_reg)
{
    static char mem_stat_reg;
    char mem_stat_aux;
    char result=MEM_STAT_REG_ERROR;
    
    if(update_stat_reg == UPDATE_STAT_REG)
    {
        MemCSEnable();                         //Habilito la memoria
        TxSPI(CMD_READ_STAT_REG);           //Consulto el registro de estado de la memoria
        mem_stat_reg = RxSPI();             //Leo la respuesta
        MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria        
    }
    mem_stat_aux = mem_stat_reg;

    if(mem_stat_aux != MEM_STAT_REG_ERROR)
    {
        switch (bit2check)
        {
            case    WEL_BIT:
                mem_stat_aux &= MASK_WEL_BIT;       //Enmascaro el registro para leer solo el EPE bit
                if(mem_stat_aux == WEL_BIT_ON)
                    result = WEL_BIT_ON;
                break;
            case    EPE_BIT:
                mem_stat_aux &= MASK_EPE_BIT;       //Enmascaro el registro para leer solo el EPE bit
                if(mem_stat_aux == EPE_BIT_NO_ERR)
                    result = EPE_BIT_NO_ERR;
                break;
            case    RDY_BSY_BIT:
                mem_stat_aux &= MASK_RDY_BSY_BIT;       //Enmascaro el registro para leer solo el EPE bit
                if(mem_stat_aux == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY)
                    result = RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY;
                break;
            case    SPM_BIT:
                mem_stat_aux &= MASK_SPM_BIT;       //Enmascaro el registro para leer solo el EPE bit
                if(mem_stat_aux == SPM_BIT_ON)
                    result = SPM_BIT_ON;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*                   Transmitir datos a memoria por SPI                       */
/******************************************************************************/
void TxSPIData2Mem(char* data,char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0)
{
    //Inicialmente, la frecuencia del SPI está configurada en 125kHz
    char aux = 0;
    //aux = data_size;
    
    do{
        MemCSEnable();                     //Habilito la memoria
        TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_EN);            //envío el comando para habilitar la escritura
        MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando

        while(MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON)
        {
            CLEAR_WDT;//reset watchdog
        }
    }while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR);
   
    MemCSEnable();                      //Habilito la memoria 
    TxSPI(CMD_SEQUENTIAL_MODE);         //Transmito comando de inicio de escritura secuencial
    TxSPI(address2);                    //Envío byte más alto de la dirección
    TxSPI(address1);                    //Envío segundo byte de dirección
    TxSPI(address0);                    //Envío byte más bajo de la dirección

    CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog

    while(aux < data_size)
    {
        while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR)
        {
            MemCSEnable();                  //Habilito la memoria
            TxSPI(CMD_SEQUENTIAL_MODE);     //Transmito comando de inicio de escritura secuencial
            TxSPI(data[aux]);               //Transmito el dato
            MemCSDisable();                 //Deshabilito la memoria para que se guarde el dato transmitido
             
            CLEAR_WDT;
        }
        aux++;
    }
    
    MemCSEnable();                         //Habilito la memoria 
    TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_DIS);               //Envío el comando para deshabilitar la escritura
    MemCSDisable();                         //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando y salir de la función      
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*         Recibir datos de memoria por SPI                                   */
/******************************************************************************/
void RxSPIMemData(char* data,char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0)
{    
    char aux = 0;
    MemCSEnable();                         //Habilito la memoria
     
    TxSPI(CMD_READ_ARRAY_LF);              //Envío comando de lectura secuencial
    TxSPI(address2);               //Envío los 3 bytes de dirección de memoria 
    TxSPI(address1);               //con el más alto primero y el más bajo último
    TxSPI(address0);
    //TxSPI(DUMMY_BYTE);                  //Para cerrar el comando se envía un byte bobo (solo HF)
    CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    
    while(aux < data_size)
    {//Levanto todas las posiciones de memoria requeridas
        data[aux] = RxSPI();
        aux++;
        CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
        __delay_us(20);
    }
     MemCSDisable();
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*       Escribir una página de memoria (256bytes) byte a byte                */
/******************************************************************************/
char MemWritePageByte (char* data, char data_size, char address2, char address1, char address0)
{
    char aux=0;
    
    do{
    MemCSEnable();                  //Habilito la memoria 
    TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_EN);            //envío el comando para habilitar la escritura
    MemCSDisable();                 //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando
    while((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON) && (MemStatRegBitCheck(RDY_BSY_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY))
    {
        CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    } 
    }while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR);
    
    MemCSEnable();
    TxSPI(CMD_BYTE_PAGE_WRITE); // Comando desproteger sector (65kB/sector)
    TxSPI(address2); // Dirección de 24 bits
    TxSPI(address1);
    TxSPI(address0);
    CLEAR_WDT; 
    //MemCSEnable();         //Habilito la memoria
    while(aux < data_size)
    {
        TxSPI(data[aux]);      //Transmito el dato
        aux++;
        __delay_us(50);
    }
    MemCSDisable();        //Deshabilito la memoria para que se guarde el dato transmitido
    if(((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON) && (aux < data_size)) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR))
    {
        if(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR)
            return EPE_ERROR;
        else
            return MEM_WRITE_ERROR;
    }
    while((MemStatRegBitCheck(RDY_BSY_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY) && (MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == EPE_BIT_NO_ERR))
    {
        CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    }
   
    return MEM_WRITE_OK;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*       Desproteger toda la memoria                                          */
/******************************************************************************/
void MemGlobalUnprotect (void)
{
    //do{
        MemCSEnable();                     //Habilito la memoria 
        TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_EN);            //envío el comando para habilitar la escritura
        MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando
        while((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == MEM_STAT_REG_ERROR))
        {
            CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
        } 
    //}while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR);
    MemCSEnable();                     //Habilito la memoria
    TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_STAT_REG);      //envío el comando para escribir el registro de estado
    TxSPI(CMD_GLOBAL_UNPROT);       //envío el comando para desproteger toda al memoria
    MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando
   
    while(MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) == WEL_BIT_ON)
    {
        CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    }
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*       Desproteger el sector de la dirección de memoria recibida            */
/******************************************************************************/
void MemUnprotectSector (char address2, char address1, char address0)
{
    do{
        MemCSEnable();                      //Habilito la memoria
        TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_EN);                //envío el comando para habilitar la escritura
        MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando
        while((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == MEM_STAT_REG_ERROR))
        {
            CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
        }
    }while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR);
    
    MemCSEnable();
    TxSPI(CMD_UNPROTECT_SECTOR); // Comando desproteger sector (65kB/sector)
    TxSPI(address2); // Dirección de 24 bits
    TxSPI(address1);
    TxSPI(address0);
    MemCSDisable();
    
    while((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) == WEL_BIT_ON) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(RDY_BSY_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY))
    {
        CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    }
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*       Borrar la memoria - por bloques o en su totalidad                    */
/******************************************************************************/
void MemErase(char block_size, char address2, char address1, char address0)
{
    do{
        do{
            MemCSEnable();              //Habilito la memoria
            TxSPI(CMD_WRITE_EN);        //envío el comando para habilitar la escritura
            MemCSDisable();             //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando 
            while((MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) != WEL_BIT_ON) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(RDY_BSY_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY))
            {
                CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
            }
        }while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR);
        MemCSEnable();
        switch (block_size)
        {
            case BLOCK_4KB:
                TxSPI(BLOCK_4KB_ERASE_CMD); // Comando 4kB Page Erase
                TxSPI(address2); // Dirección de 24 bits
                TxSPI(address1);
                TxSPI(address0);
                break;
            case BLOCK_32KB:
                TxSPI(BLOCK_32KB_ERASE_CMD); // Comando 32kB Page Erase
                TxSPI(address2); // Dirección de 24 bits
                TxSPI(address1);
                TxSPI(address0);
                break; 
            case BLOCK_64KB:
                TxSPI(BLOCK_64KB_ERASE_CMD); // Comando 64kB Page Erase
                TxSPI(address2); // Dirección de 24 bits
                TxSPI(address1);
                TxSPI(address0);
                break;
            case ALL_BLOCKS:            
                TxSPI(ALL_BLOCKS_ERASE_CMD);    //envío el comando para borrar todos los bloques de memoria
                break;    
        }
        MemCSDisable();                     //Deshabilito la memoria para que se efectúe el comando
        while(((MemStatRegBitCheck(RDY_BSY_BIT,UPDATE_STAT_REG) == RDY_BSY_BIT_BUSY) || (MemStatRegBitCheck(WEL_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == WEL_BIT_ON))&&(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) == EPE_BIT_NO_ERR))
        {
            CLEAR_WDT;   //reset watchdog
        } 
    }while(MemStatRegBitCheck(EPE_BIT,NO_UPDATE_STAT_REG) != EPE_BIT_NO_ERR); 
    
}

char MemReadDeviceID (char* data)
{
    MemCSEnable();                         //Habilito la memoria
     
    TxSPI(CMD_READ_DEV_ID);              //Envío comando de lectura del device ID

    data[0] = RxSPI();          //Recibo el primer byte que corresponde al ID del fabricante (0x1F -> AT26DF161A)
    data[1] = RxSPI();          //Recibo la parte 1 del ID del dispositivo (0x46 -> AT26DF161A)
    data[2] = RxSPI();          //Recibo la parte 2 del ID del dispositivo (0x01 -> AT26DF161A)
    data[3] = RxSPI();          //Recibo el extended device info (0x00 -> AT26DF161A)
    CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
    __delay_us(20);
  
    MemCSDisable();
    
    if(data[0]!=0x1F || data[1]!=0x46 || data[2]!=0x01)
        return DEV_ID_NOK;
    else
        return DEV_ID_OK;
}

Here is the main program
#include "PIC16F883_HAL_functions.h"
#include "MEM_HAL_functions.h"

char devID[4];

char tick2mS = 0;   //contador cada 2,048mS
char tick100mS = 0; //contador cada 100mS

char byte_recibido;
char flag_rx = 0;

char key_in=0;

#define SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE    20
//char spi_comm_buffer[SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE]={0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0xFF};
char spi_comm_buffer[SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'};
char spi_out_buffer[SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE];

void main(void) 
{
    char test = 'X';
    configuracion();
    if(OSCILADOR_ESTABLE)
    {
        MEM_CS_OFF;
        
        TxUART(&test,1);
        MemGlobalUnprotect();
        if(MemReadDeviceID (devID)==DEV_ID_NOK)
            TxUART(devID,3);
        else
        {
            TxUART(&devID[1],1);
            TxUART(&devID[2],1);
        }
        
        //MemErase(ALL_BLOCKS,0,0,0);
    
        while (1) 
        {
            while(key_in != 'R')
            {
                CLEAR_WDT;
                RxUART(&key_in,1);
            }
            TxUART(spi_comm_buffer, SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE);
            key_in = 0;
            __delay_ms(10);
            CLEAR_WDT; //reset watchdog
            
            if(tick2mS>=49)
                tick100mS++;
            
            MemUnprotectSector (SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            __delay_ms(2);
            MemErase(BLOCK_4KB,SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            __delay_ms(2);
            MemUnprotectSector (SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            __delay_ms(2);
            //TxSPIData2Mem(spi_comm_buffer,SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE,SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            while(MemWritePageByte(spi_comm_buffer,SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE,SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0)!=MEM_WRITE_OK)
            {}
            __delay_ms(500);
            MemUnprotectSector (SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            __delay_ms(2);
            RxSPIMemData(spi_out_buffer, SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE,SCREEN0_ADD_2,SCREEN0_ADD_1,SCREEN0_ADD_0);
            __delay_ms(500);
            TxUART(spi_out_buffer, SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE);
            __delay_ms(5);
            TxUART(spi_comm_buffer, SPI_COMM_BUFFER_SIZE);
            __delay_ms(500);

        }
    }
}

#include    "PIC16F883_HAL_functions.h"

void configuracion(void)
{
    // Configuraci?n del oscilador, el timer0  y el WD
    FREQUENCY_SELECT = FREQ_8MHZ;//Internal Oscillator Frequency Select bits, 111 = 8 MHz
    SYS_CLOCK_SEL = SYS_CLK_INTERNAL_OSC;
    ANSEL = 0b00000000;
    ANSELH = 0b00000000;
    TFT_DB0_IO = OUTPUT;
    TFT_DB1_IO = OUTPUT;
    TFT_DB2_IO = OUTPUT;  
    TFT_DB3_IO = OUTPUT; 
    TFT_DB4_IO = OUTPUT; 
    uC_SPI_CS_IO = OUTPUT;
    TFT_DB6_IO = OUTPUT; 
    TFT_DB5_IO = OUTPUT;

    TFT_RD_IO = OUTPUT;        
    TFT_WR_IO = OUTPUT;     
    TFT_RS_IO = OUTPUT;       
    TFT_RESET_IO = OUTPUT;  
    TFT_CS_IO = OUTPUT;      
    PUERTO_LIBRE0_IO = INPUT;  
    ICSPCLK_IO = INPUT;       
    ICSPDAT_IO = INPUT;    

    TFT_DB7_IO = OUTPUT;      
    PUERTO_LIBRE1_IO = INPUT;  
    MEM_CS_IO = OUTPUT;   
    SPI_CK_IO = OUTPUT;  
    SPI_DI_IO = INPUT;   
    SPI_DO_IO = OUTPUT;  
    UART_TX_IO = OUTPUT; 
    UART_RX_IO = INPUT; 
            
    PORTA = 0;
    PORTB = 0;
    PORTC = 0;
    
    nPORTB_PULLUPS=1;//PORTB pull-ups are disabled
    
    TIMER0_CLK_SOURCE = CLK_SRC_INT_OSC;//0 = Internal instruction cycle clock (FOSC/4)
    PRESCALER_ASSIGNMENT = PSA_WDT;//1 = Prescaler is assigned to the WDT
    TMR0=0;//
    
    WDT_PRESCALER = 0b0111;//1;4096
    //WDTCONbits.SWDTEN=1;//watchdog habilitado (software enable)
    
    // Configuraci?n de interrupciones  
    GENERAL_INT_EN = 1;     //habilito irq general
    PERIF_INT_EN = 0;       //habilito irq perifericos   
    TIMER0_INT_EN = 1;      //habilito irq por Timer0
    flag_TIMER0_INT = 0;    //flag de irq x timer overflow 
    
    //Configuracion SPI
    configSPI();
    //Configuración UART
    configUSART();
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                          */
/******************************************************************************/
void configSPI(void)
{
    SPI_SAMPLE_BIT_CONF = 0;    //Input data sampled at middle of data output time
    SPI_CKP_CONF = 1;           //El estado idle del clock es en '1'
    SPI_CKE_CONF = 0;           //Con CKP=1, Data transmitted on falling edge of SCK
    SPI_PORTMODE_CONF = 0b0010; //SPI master mode - clock Fosc/64 (Fosc 8MHz - Fck 125kHz)
    
    SPI_EN = 1;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*               Enviar datos por SPI                                           */
/******************************************************************************/
void TxSPI (char data)
{
    SPI_BUFFER = data;
    while (!SPI_BUFFER_FULL_FLAG)     // Esperar a que la transmisión termine
        CLEAR_WDT;
}
/******************************************************************************/
/*                  Recibir daots por SPI                                     */
/******************************************************************************/
char RxSPI (void)
{
    SPI_BUFFER = SPI_EMPTY_BYTE;        // Iniciar la recepción enviando un byte nulo
    while (!SPI_BUFFER_FULL_FLAG)       // Esperar a que la recepción termine
        CLEAR_WDT;
    
    return SPI_BUFFER;                  // Devolver el dato recibido
}

EDIT2
The schematics is this:

The PCB layout:

Any help? Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

What did you write, and what did you read back? Did you perform an erase before the write?

0x1f is Atmel, and 0x58 is "MHS Electronic" (at least in bank 1...) ... do you have a genuine Atmel/Microchip part, or a compatible from another manufacturer?

The array I'm sending to the memory is this: {41h 42h 43h 44h 45h 46h 47h 48h 49h 4Ah 4Bh 4Ch 4Dh 4Eh 4Fh 50h 00h 00h 00h 00h} (in ascii is {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}... and the response is: {43h 0Ah 28h 12h 4Dh 24h ? 62h ? 2Ch ? ? ? 32h ? 30h 00h 00h 00h 00h}
Yes, first I unprotect the sector, then I perform a 4kB erase and then I write, If I don't do this, the response is all 0xFF
The chip is marked as Atmel, I don't know why the response is another manufacturer.

I've made another call, and now the response was {43h 0Ah 28h 12h 4Dh 24h ? 51h 59h ? 5Dh 45h 65h ? 75h 18h 00h 00h 00h 00h}, after this call, the response was always the same.

Please add this information to your question using the edit button. Can you clarify what the ? characters represent?

Can you post the schematics and PCB layout?

I have some ideas. Why not check the waveforms with an oscilloscope? Even if the clock is 125 kHz, it will be very rounded due to the resistors used for level shifting. Is there a possibility to use a 5V flash or change the MCU to 3.3V?

Finally, I've changed the power source of the PIC from 5V to 3,3V. I have removed all the attenuators and the memory started working ok. I thought that at 125kHz the resistors attenuator would work just fine, but I was wrong.
Thanks to all who helped!!
Regards.
